# Extending Zend_Log for application-specific need

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am building a Zend Framework application that performs jobs submitted by the user.  The actions taken need to be logged to a database.  I would like to correlate the job with its log entries.

Instead of creating my own logging class, I would like to extend Zend_Log since it provides 99% of the functionality that I need.  All I need to do is add a foreign key of the job id to the log data model.

Is this possible?

I'm also looking for a good example of Zend_Log writing to a database.  I haven't searched SO yet.  I will do that after I post this.

Thanks in advance...

Steve

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/markushausammann/monitorix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to extend `Zend_Log`. The framework's code is open, and pretty clean. In the easiest case, you should be able to get going by creating a class in a new file that `extends Zend_Log`.

Maybe one of our resident ZF experts can elaborate with more detailed info on how to do this in practice.

> I'm also looking for a good example of Zend_Log writing to a database

Zend_Log already has a database connector. See [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html) for an example.